# Sql Query for finding a certain frequency distribution

Tags: mysql, sql

This table is updated whenever a customer buys anything:

#### table 1

- customerid
- item

I want to find out a query to know the frequency distribution of number of customers and number of items bought. For example the number of customers who have bought 1 item, 2 items and so on.

Comment: I could get the count for each user using the count(*) and group by `customerid` . Couldn't think further.

Comment: You probably need to give us more of schema, such as what does table 1 represent. Orders?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select items_bought, count(*) as customers
from (
    select customerid, count(*) as items_bought
    from your_table
    group by customerid
) dt
group by items_bought
```

First you group by `customerid` to get your counts and then group by the counts to get your histogram values. This will give you the number of items bought in `items_bought` and the number of customers that bought that many in `customers`.

Comment: Excellent answer, could you explain how to modify the query for the case that we want the number of distinct items bought ?